# Pyspark SQL select all rows which matches pattern using LIKE not working

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this CSV file:

```
CodiceFiscale;IVA;RAE;SAE
RDCRLR97F07F839F;11111111111;123;123
rdcrlr97f07f839f;11111111111;123;123
errorctrl1 ;34;12;1
error;12;12;1113
```

And I want to select all the rows where the column `codicefiscale` follows this pattern: `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]`.

I have made this query on pyspark sql:

```sql
SELECT * FROM soggetti WHERE CodiceFiscale LIKE ('[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]')
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: If you are looking for strings such as `'[A-Z]'` then your code is fine.  If you think these are character classes, then you are confusing `like` with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex : `^[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{3}[A-Z]$` with [`rlike`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#rlike) SQL function.

The qualifier `{n}` mean it matches exactly `n` times. You need also to add `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) to match the entire `CodiceFiscale` :

```
data = [
    ("RDCRLR97F07F839F", 11111111111, 123, 123),
    ("rdcrlr97f07f839f", 11111111111, 123, 123),
    ("errorctrl1", 34, 12, 1),
    ("error", 12, 12, 1113)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["CodiceFiscale", "IVA", "RAE", "SAE"])

df.createOrReplaceTempView("soggetti")

spark.sql("""
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    soggetti 
    WHERE   CodiceFiscale RLIKE '^[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{3}[A-Z]$'
""").show() 

#+----------------+-----------+---+---+
#|   CodiceFiscale|        IVA|RAE|SAE|
#+----------------+-----------+---+---+
#|RDCRLR97F07F839F|11111111111|123|123|
#+----------------+-----------+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `rlike` if you want to use regular expressions in the filter. Your regular expression could be simplified - repeating patterns could be represented using curly brackets.

```
select *
from soggetti
where CodiceFiscale rlike '[A-Z]{6}([0-9]{2}[A-Z]){2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]'
```